# Import of Ecoinvent 2.2 and Ecoinvent 3.x fail with Brightway

Tags: brightway

The import of Ecoinvent 2.2 and 3.x does not happen. I do not understand what is the issue here.

I have downloaded both 2 and 3 versions from Ecoinvent.org but both the Ecospold1 and 2 importers show me the same (or the lack of) results.

```
`from brightway2 import *

ei33cutoff = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(
    r"C:\Users\HS254581\Documents\test\ecoinvent33cutoff\datasets",
    "ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff"
)

ei33cutoff.apply_strategies()
ei33cutoff.statistics()`
```

All I get is

```
"Extracting XML data from 13831 datasets"
```

WITHOUT any error message. I have kept it running for hours sometimes, ultimately I have to quit.

I can however import Forwast database, do some LCA calculations here and some CSV files from Simapro.

I read most of the questions answered here and on github, but cannot find a solution to this problem. 
Send help!

P.S. I am using Python 3.7 with Spyder. Here I need to activate bw2 environment in Anaconda prompt and set Python interpreter path to default. Have installed kernels too. This is the only way it seems to work. Also updated conda and brightway packages today just in case.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without a little more information. Are you sure you are downloading the correct version of ecoinvent (https://docs.brightwaylca.org/faq.html#which-ecoinvent-file-should-i-download)? What OS are you on?

Comment: Hello Chris, I am using Windows 10 and yes I am sure, I am using the correct version of Ecoinvent. Here is the name of my file I downloaded from Ecoinvent: ecoinvent 3.3_cutoff_ecoSpold02.7z I also downloaded some processes for Ecoinvent 2.2. I have the same issue.

Comment: @Hemants does bw2setup() create the database of biosphere flows ?

Comment: @Nabla yes, I can check the installed database as ```Databases dictionary with 3 object(s):
        PVind
        biosphere3
        forwast``` and if i check the length of biosphere3, its 4246. I also have the same import issue with another laptop

Comment: Pretty much stumped, as others are using your setup without problems. Maybe try `Ecospold...Importer(..., use_mp=False)`.

Comment: Okay I found what the issue was. I used ```use_mp=False``` which resulted in 'Python has stopped working -> close program' and the kernel dying in Spyder. So I used the Python interpreter in Anaconda prompt, I could write the Database with 0 unlinked exchanges. Thanks for your help @ChrisMutel, @Nabla. Is there a preferred interpreter on Windows 10?